# Determining the best constant $\frac{b+c}{a^k+1}+\frac{c+a}{b^k+1}+\frac{a+b}{c^k+1}\ge a+b+c.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Find positive constant $k$ such that the following inequality holds$$\frac{b+c}{a^k+1}+\frac{c+a}{b^k+1}+\frac{a+b}{c^k+1}\ge a+b+c.$$
I prove in case $k=3$ $$\frac{b+c}{a^3+1}+\frac{c+a}{b^3+1}+\frac{a+b}{c^3+1}\ge a+b+c.$$
By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a^3+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc(b+c)}{a^2+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\left(b+c-\frac{a^2(b+c)}{a^2+bc}\right).$$Thus, it suffices to show$$\frac{a^2(b+c)}{a^2+bc}+\frac{b^2(a+c)}{b^2+ac}+\frac{c^2(b+a)}{c^2+ba}\le a+b+c.$$Also by C-S$$\frac{a^2(b+c)}{a^2+bc}=a^2.\frac{(b+c)^2}{(b+c)(a^2+bc)}\le\frac{a^2c}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^2b}{a^2+c^2}.$$Similarly, $(*)$ is true and equality holds at $a=b=c=1.$

Back on the main problem, I'm not sure $k=3$ is the greatest constant.

Could you please share a systematic approach to determine $k$? Thank you for you help.